# Changing numbers in theorems

Tags: numbering

I want the number in the first theorem to be 1.1 and not 1.0.1. The number 1.1.1 of the second theorem is right. What can I do?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{theorem}[subsection]

\begin{document}
\section{1st section}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\subsection{1st subsection}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Well, you didn't use a subsection before the first theorem, that's why the numbering is wrong, but you can try `\counterwithin{thm}{section}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\counterwithin{thm}{subsection}`, after `\section{1st section}` -- this requires `\usepackage{chngcntr}`

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the subsection number is 0 and, in this case, issue `\thesection`, otherwise issue `\thesubsection`.

Your readers will be confused by this numbering system.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{empheq}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsection]

\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
  \ifnum\value{subsection}>0 
    \thesubsection
  \else
    \thesection
  \fi
  .\arabic{thm}%
}

\begin{document}
\section{1st section}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\subsection{1st subsection}
\begin{thm}
Some theorem.
\end{thm}
\end{document}
```

[image]